Using a pointer to a structure returned by a C++ DLL
I'm using functions of a C++ DLL from Delphi (dynamic linking with LoadLibrary).
Amongst these, get_all_hook_functions_V2() can return a pointer to a structure populated with functions adresses, that I can replace with addresses of my own functions and send back (a callback mechanism that allows the library to perfom tasks using my own functions).
Whatever I tried (except AVS) I get 0 zeroes and nil in the structure returned.
A typical usage in C is shown below:
static HOOKFCNS2 hfcns;

void ELCALLBACK remap_cal_target(INT16 x, INT16 y)
{
    // ... code to handle draw_cal_target_hook goes here
}

// remap single hook function to be called for calibration target drawing
void setup_remap_hooks(void)
{
    HOOKFCNS2 *hooks = get_all_hook_functions_V2();
    memcpy(&hfcns,hooks,sizeof(HOOKFCNS2));
    hooks->draw_cal_target_hook = remap_cal_target;
    setup_graphic_hook_functions_V2(hooks);
}

The original definition of HOOKFCNS2 is here:
typedef struct
{
    /*!Major version. At the moment the version number must be set to 1 */
    int major;
    /*!Minor version. At the moment the version number must be set to 0 */
    int minor;
    /*!The value set here will be passed to every single call back functions */
    void *userData;
    INT16  (ELCALLBACK * setup_cal_display_hook)(void *userData);
    INT16   (ELCALLBACK * exit_cal_display_hook)(void *userData) ;
    INT16  (ELCALLBACK * setup_image_display_hook)(void *userData,INT16 width, INT16 height) ;
    INT16   (ELCALLBACK * image_title_hook)(void *userData,char *title) ;
    INT16   (ELCALLBACK * draw_image)(void *userData,INT16 width, INT16 height,byte *pixels) ;
    INT16   (ELCALLBACK * exit_image_display_hook)(void *userData) ;
    INT16   (ELCALLBACK * clear_cal_display_hook)(void *userData) ;
    INT16   (ELCALLBACK * erase_cal_target_hook)(void *userData);
    INT16   (ELCALLBACK * draw_cal_target_hook)(void *userData,float x, float y);
    INT16   (ELCALLBACK * play_target_beep_hook)(void *userData,EL_CAL_BEEP beep_type) ;
    INT16  (ELCALLBACK * get_input_key_hook)(void *userData,InputEvent * event);
    INT16   (ELCALLBACK * alert_printf_hook)(void *userData, const char *msg);
    int reserved1;
    int reserved2;
    int reserved3;
    int reserved4;
}HOOKFCNS2;

My translation of all this in Delphi (calling conventions for the DLL are aliases to stdcall: WINAPI and CALLBACK):
TYPE
    Tsetup_cal_display   = function(userData: pointer): INT16; stdcall;
    Texit_cal_display    = function(userData: pointer): INT16; stdcall;
    Tsetup_image_display = function(userData: pointer; width, height: INT16): INT16; stdcall;
    Timage_title         = function(userData: pointer; title: pAnsiChar): INT16; stdcall;
    Tdraw_image          = function(userData: pointer; width, height: INT16; pixels: pbyte): INT16;  stdcall;
    Texit_image_display  = function(userData: pointer): INT16; stdcall;
    Tclear_cal_display   = function(userData: pointer): INT16; stdcall;
    Terase_cal_target    = function(userData: pointer): INT16; stdcall;
    Tdraw_cal_target     = function(userData: pointer; x, y: float): INT16; stdcall;
    TPlay_target_beep    = function(userData: pointer; beep_type: INT16): INT16; stdcall;
    Tget_input_key       = function(userData: pointer; key_input: TInputEventPtr): INT16; stdcall;
    Talert_printf        = function(userData: pointer; msg: PAnsiChar): INT16; stdcall;


    THOOKFCNS2 = record
      major,
      minor :                   int_;
      UserData:                 pointer;
      setup_cal_display_hook:   Tsetup_cal_display;    // This function is called to setup calibration/validation display. This function called before any calibration routines are called.
      exit_cal_display_hook:    Texit_cal_display;     // This is called to release any resources that are not required beyond calibration. Beyond this call, no calibration functions will be called.
      setup_image_display_hook: Tsetup_image_display;  // This function is responsible for initializing any resources that are required for camera setup. Retuns -1 / 0 / 1;
      image_title_hook:         Timage_title;          // This function is called to update any image title change.
      draw_image_hook:          Tdraw_image;           // This function is called to supply the image line by line from top to bottom.
      exit_image_display_hook:  Texit_image_display;   // This is called to notify that all camera setup things are complete. Any resources that are allocated in setup_image_display can be released in this function.
      clear_cal_display_hook:   Tclear_cal_display;    // Called to clear the calibration display.
      erase_cal_target_hook:    Terase_cal_target;     // This function is responsible for erasing the target that was drawn by the last call to draw_cal_target.
      draw_cal_target_hook:     Tdraw_cal_target;      // This function is responsible for the drawing of the target for calibration,validation and drift correct at the given coordinate.
      play_target_beep_hook:    TPlay_target_beep;     // This function is called to signal new target.
      get_input_key_hook:       Tget_input_key;        //
      alert_printf_hook:        Talert_printf;         // This function is called whenever alert_printf is called.
      reserved1,
      reserved2,
      reserved3,
      reserved4:                int_;
    end;

THookFcns2Ptr = THookFcns2^;

VAR
   GDI_HookFcns2: THookFcns2;

TYPE
    // HOOKFCNS2 *  get_all_hook_functions_V2 (void) 
    Tget_all_hook_functions_V2 = function: THookFcns2Ptr; stdcall;
VAR
   get_all_hook_functions_V2: Tget_all_hook_functions_V2;

  // In the program, later ...

 GDI_HookFcns2:= get_all_hook_functions_V2()^;

GDI_HookFcns2 contains (0, 0, nil, nil ..., 0, 0, 0, 0);
I also tried GDI_HookFcns2:= THookFcns2Ptr(get_all_hook_functions_V2())^;... nothing better.
I tried GDI_HookFcns2 as a THookFcns2Ptr, allocating memory (GetMem) ... nothing better.
The DLL-providing company confirmed that the function returns something else than 0 and nil.
I tried to set values (major:=2, for example) in the GDI_HookFcns2 before calling the function, and after then it is set to zero.
Is it because of a different compiler way of returning structure? An error in pointer addressing?

Did you make sure the size and alignment of the Delphi record and its fields all match the C struct? Also, not related to the problem, but you don't need memcpy/copymemory to copy a record, a simple assignment will suffice, eg (C) hfcns = *hooks; (Delphi) GDI_HookFcns2 := get_all_hook_functions_V2()^;

I've asked the manufacturer about alignement and size. For now, I've just got some .h header files

Try declaring THookFcns2 with packed record, or applying {$ALIGN 4|8} to it. Do you have access to using this DLL in a C/C++ project that you can compare results with? Do you know what value sizeof(HOOKFCNS2) returns in C/C++?

Size and alignment are important, but they can't be the only issue here. The original structure's major field is non-zero, so there would be something in the structure, maybe garbled but not just all zeros. Personally I'd drop down to debugger here, and traced disassembly to check what exactly happens during get_all_hook_functions_V2 call - does it return proper address? Is there something sane at that address? What happens to that address later in the code?

@AndreyTurkin: you got the point. The DLL provider (SR Research Ltd.) tested on its side, with C++15 compiler and got the same result ! They directed me to an other structure (HOOKFCNS), pretty close to this one. Just a few fields to modify and the Delphi code works like a charm. Topic solved !

@RemyLebeau: thanks for clarification on pointers, memory management and editing my code. it works ok.
